# What does the variable name in the register declaration indicate (Verilog)

Tags: verilog

I'm a just starting to learn verilog , and I'm having trouble with some things. I've found a few resources to help, but there are some things which aren't clear and I need specified. I have code for a D Flip-flop below. And I understand how the declaration for in and out work. What I dont get is the register.

When it says out is the variable associated with it.Does this association mean, out is the register along with output? Or does it mean out is also the output for the register?

```
module DFF(quarter, in, out) ;
parameter n = 1;           // width
input quarter ;
input  [n-1:0] in ;
output [n-1:0] out ;
reg    [n-1:0] out ;
always @(quarter=1) 
 out = in ;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

In Verilog there are *nets* and there are *variables*. The most common kind of net by far is a *wire*, which you're probably familiar with. You can declare a variable using `var`, but most people say `reg`, because that is how it always has been done.

(In Verilog, but not in SystemVerilog), wires have to be driven by

- `assign` statements
- the outputs of instantiated modules

and variables have to be driven from

- `initial` and `always` blocks.

Your output `out` is driven from an `always` block and so must be a variable. The line

```
reg    [n-1:0] out ;
```

declares the output `out` as being a variable (rather than a wire).

In fact, you are using an old-fashioned way of specifying inputs and outputs. Since 2001, the way to do it is like this:

```
module DFF #(parameter n = 1) 
            (input wire         quarter, 
             input wire [n-1:0] in, 
             output reg [n-1:0] out);

always @(quarter=1) 
  out = in ;

endmodule
```

This is the so-called *ANSI* form and, I think you would agree, is more sensible. I would advise using this form, not the old-fashioned form you are using.

BTW, you code is a bit strange. I'm not entirely sure what it's supposed to do, but this if you're expecting output to be driven by in  when quarter is 1, I'd do it more like this:

```
module DFF // #(parameter n = 1) // you're not using parameter n
            (input wire         quarter, 
             input wire [n-1:0] in, 
             output reg [n-1:0] out);

always @(*) 
  if (quarter == 1'b1)
    out = in ;
  else
    // IMPORTANT ! : what is out when quarter != 1 ? 
    // your current code would synthesise to a latch
    // is that what you wanted? (And if so, are you
    // sure that's what you wanted)

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

initially verilog was though as a language which does behavioral types of operation on state variables (registers, reg) and connects them via `nets`. So, `reg` is a variable which is supposed to keep its value between operations, `net` is just a connection and has no state associated with it, i.e. `wire`. `reg` values can be calculated in `procedural` blocks, i.e. `always` block, `wires` can be connected only (using continuous assignments, `assign` statements (outside of the always blocks)).

There are different rules for using for `reg`s and `wire`s and different behavior of them in simulation, in particular around multiple drivers.  See Matthew's reply for more info.